# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I want to build an app bundle for my flutter project, however I get an exception every time. Here is the terminal message:

```
 Building with sound null safety 

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/ahmet/Documents/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter_android-2.1.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/ahmet/Documents/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/libphonenumber-2.0.2/android/src/main/java/com/codeheadlabs/libphonenumber/LibphonenumberPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/ahmet/Documents/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location/FlutterLocation.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR:/Users/ahmet/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/df9b61f0f2e66d13a646c74f00bdcc6f/transformed/jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar: R8: Type org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.edec.KeyFactorySpi$Ed25519 is defined multiple times: /Users/ahmet/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/df9b61f0f2e66d13a646c74f00bdcc6f/transformed/jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:META-INF/versions/11/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/edec/KeyFactorySpi$Ed25519.class, /Users/ahmet/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/df9b61f0f2e66d13a646c74f00bdcc6f/transformed/jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/edec/KeyFactorySpi$Ed25519.class

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/ahmet/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/df9b61f0f2e66d13a646c74f00bdcc6f/transformed/jetified-bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:META-INF/versions/11/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/edec/KeyFactorySpi$Ed25519.class

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 6m 10s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            374,1s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I assume the error is related to some kind of Java stuff because of the `KeyFactorySpi$Ed25519.class` but I can not end up with something meaningful.

`pubspec.yaml`

```
name: fortinayn
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.7.1+27

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # carousel_pro: ^1.0.0 (outdated)
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  card_swiper: ^2.0.4
  location: ^4.4.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.12
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  sleek_circular_slider: ^2.0.1
  geolocator: ^9.0.1
  # geocoder: ^0.2.1 (outdated)
  http: ^0.13.5
  provider: ^6.0.3
  # progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  progress_dialog_null_safe: ^1.0.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.4.1
  #search_map_place: ^0.3.0
  pattern_formatter: ^2.0.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  # splashscreen: ^1.3.5 (outdated)
  easy_splash_screen: ^1.0.4
  share: ^2.0.4
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  fl_chart: ^0.55.1
  # flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0 (discontinued)
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1+1
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.4
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
  # apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0 (discontinued)
  sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.11

  # firebase_analytics: ^5.0.11
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "dev_assets/logo.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FC7F23"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf
          weight: 900
    - family: Alata
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Alata-Regular.ttf
    - family: MyFlutterApp
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1,0.99.99]'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`app/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mcc.fortinaynn"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

       signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`flutter doctor -v`

```
ahmet@192 ~ % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on macOS 13.0 22A5365d darwin-x64, locale
    tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.3.3 on channel stable at
      /Users/ahmet/Documents/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18a827f393 (8 days ago), 2022-09-28 10:03:14 -0700
    • Engine revision 5c984c26eb
    • Dart version 2.18.2
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/ahmet/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/ahmet/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.50.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'` was causing this problem. I assume that it conflicts with the `flutter_facebook_auth` package added via `pubspec.yaml` file. I removed this dependency and now everything is just working fine.

Comment: Then you should accept your own answer.  It's the little tic symbol you see below the vote arrows, next to your answer.

Comment: I was waiting for the 4 hours limit. Thanks for reminder :)

Comment: Nice! :) ______